# Icons disappeared from launcher?

Tags: icons, launcher

I was moving my mouse but my slippery hand did something that made the icons disappear. What do I do?

Edit: I fixed it, suspend your PC and turn it on again. But I have a new question, how did I make them disappear with the mouse?

Comment: Post last edit as answer.

Comment: @N0rbert OK.⠀⠀⠀

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You suspend your PC, then turn it on again.